# Call a method function inside an async Method Function

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have two methods:
`method_1` and `aysnc method_2`;
I would like to call `method_1` inside the `aysnc method_2` (after retrieving some Data);

(`aysnc method_2` catches Data and pass it into `method_1` and executes it.)

I use `this.method_1` inside the `aysnc method_2` to call it, but nothing happens.

```
method_1 (data) {
    console.log( 'I need it here', data );
} ,

triggerByUser () {

    this.method_1( 'just a test' );

    async function method_2 () {

        let code = await fileRetriever( 'songs' );
        console.log( 'this code retrieved: ' ,  code );
        this.method_1( code );
        console.log( 'the code has been sent!' );

    } ;

    method_2 (  ) ;
},
```

result:

```
JS: 'I need it here' 'just a test'
JS: 'response From fileRetriever:' 58
JS: 'this code retrieved: ' 58
```

( Project is written on NativeScript + Vue )

Comment: "I would like to call `method_1` **after completing** the `async method_2`" _next_ "but as I use this.method_1 **inside** the `aysnc method_2` , happens nothing.". 1. Add the actual code. 2. **After** OR **inside** ? 3. Better if you can provide a codepen or something similar.

Comment: as you can see it stuck on this line `this.method_1( data.length );`

Comment: @Max I hope it would be clear by now. :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that I need to pass it as a callback;

```
triggerByUser () {

    this.method_1( 'just a test' );

    async function method_2 ( callback ) {

        let code = await fileRetriever( 'songs' );
        console.log( 'this code retrieved: ' ,  code );
        callback( code );
        console.log( 'the code has been sent!' );

    } ;

    method_2 ( this.method_1 ) ;
},
```

result:

```
JS: 'I need it here' 'just a test'
JS: 'response From fileRetriever:' 58
JS: 'this code retrieved: ' 58
JS: 'I need it here' 58
JS: 'the code has been sent!'
```

Is there any better approach?! (since using **async + callback** seems a bit dirty to me )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Nativescript but as I can read from the intro seems that Vue Component is the same of the *classic* Vue.

You have nested `method_2` inside the `triggerByUser` if you move it outside , into the `methods`, and call it with `await` all function correctly

```
methods:{
    method_1 (data) {
      console.log( 'I need it here', data );
    },
    async triggerByUser () {
        this.method_1( 'just a test' );
        await this.method_2();
    },
    async method_2 () {

        let code = await fileRetriever( 'songs' );
        console.log( 'this code retrieved: ' ,  code );
        this.method_1( code );
        console.log( 'the code has been sent!' );

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well very simple..

create two methods and call them in a third async method

For example, you have to run two ajax calls when user clicks on an anchor tag then you will do it like this.

```
<template>
    <div>
         <a @click="getDataFromTwoOtherMethods()">Click here</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
    ...
    methods:{
       method1(){},
       method2(){},


       async getDataFromTwoOtherMethods(){
            await this.method1();
            this.method2();
            //this method will wait for method1 to execute 
            //and get response and then call second method
       } 
   },
</script>
```